# How to identify that web requests are sent from the library that I've created

Tags: android, ios, security, authentication, sdk

I have a backend server, and want to provide an SDK for connecting to that backend server. The sdk is going to be built for iOS and Android and will ship as a library separate for those platforms.

The problem is I want to make sure that the requests are sent only using the sdk that I provide. Basically everybody knows that it is possible to monitor WEB requests using proxy applications like Fiddler or Charles proxy. And it is possible to usurp the requests and send those requests manually as many times as one wants.

For my scenario should be made impossible. So I need a way to identify in the backend that the request that I've received is for sure sent from my sdk. How can I achieve this?

EDIT1:
I can guess something like [digipasses](http://www.vasco.com/products/client_products/single_button_digipass/digipass_go6.aspx) may be used. For instance when I log into my bank account I get one time password and log in. But that is based on time, and I can not count on the time of device. May be we can reuse the concept.

Thanks for answers!

Comment: "How can I achieve this?" -- you don't. By definition, your HTTP requests from your SDK are a series of bytes. Anything else can create the same series of bytes. Your server has know way to know the provenance of that series of bytes.

Comment: I suppose you could ask Alice and Bob how they solved their problem...

Comment: Implement an access token between client and server. Encrypt and Decrypt it accordingly. you can use IMEI code or MAC address to make your access token.

Comment: To Veger: I've thought about Alice and Bob, but they didn't help me :)
To Parvaz: I can use, but if some grabs my requests and reuses them on the same device, those requests will work. I need to ensure that if someone captures my requests they won't be able to submit those requests to server, and server will refuse those requests.